# Test both tails in distributions comparison

Tags: kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I have several distributions that can be pretty skewed, like the example. I can use KS test to asses if they are different but I'm also interested in testing the single tails separately.

What would be the best approach if I want to answer the question is red distribution different than black regarding negative values and then again for positive values.

Would it make sense to test each tail separately?
[image]